# How to handle user authentications in a Service-Oriented Architecture using 'memcached'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to handle user authentications in a [Service-Oriented Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) (SOA).

At this time I have 3 applications located (for now) on the same server:

- pjtname.com
- users.pjtname.com
- others.pjtname.com

I would like to use `memcached` (it is a very awesome way to avoid to query the database), but I've heard of problems that can happen when the system goes out of memory, such as the problem for users not being able to log.

However, I am thinking to store in the `pjtname.com` cache at least the `user_id` values so that is more hard to go out of memory. The following are steps at what I am thinking to do, but I don't know if it is the best way to accomplish what I aim.

1. send user credentials from `pjtname.com` to `users.pjtname.com` over SSL;
2. on the `users.pjtname.com` side use a middleware to intercept and sign in the user;
3. on sign in success, send back the user session authentication information (example: the `user_id` string) from `users.pjtname.com` to `pjtname.com` over SSL;
4. on the `pjtname.com` side look for `user_id` in cache and if that is expired start again at the step 1.

So, **do you advice to use `memcached` for that purpose?**

- **If so, where I can start?**
- **If no, what approach is recommended?**

---

**UPDATE** for **@Mörre** comment

> Why do you want to send authentication
>   info between the sites, can't they
>   just get the session data from the
>   (same) database?

It is because I am trying to scale RoR applications on different servers each of them with its own database.

> To give architecture advice one would
>   have to see the WHOLE picture, what
>   your task is from the customers point
>   of view, and know their intentions and
>   constraints.

The "picture" is that I have 3 RoR applications (`pjtname.com`, `users.pjtname.com` and `others.pjtname.com`) for which I need to handle data in order to improve the whole system performance. In this case I need to handle user session on a central place (`pjtname.com`) in order to access to the other application datas (`users.pjtname.com` and `others.pjtname.com`) only if the current user is authenticated, that is, signed in.

Comment: waaaaaayy too little data to advice. One would need to know A LOT more about your situation, app, requirements, etc. memcached is just a cache, your question is one of high(est)-level system architecture. And you put in a buzz word (SOA) too, now it makes even less sense. But why would you cache the login process of all that there is to cache? Everyone does it just ONCE, why is it critical if it's done in 1ms vs. 100ms???

Comment: ...and yes, when a memcache is full it silently discards data according to an LRU algorithm (least recently used). It's a CACHE, not a DB replacement.

Comment: If you had said "session", okay, but you said "authentication". I would have understood why someone would want to accelerate access to the session store, because that's used again and again. But authentication?

Comment: @Mörre What requirements do you need to know? Just say and I will provide information...

Comment: I don't think you can do that (well enough) here. This website is good for specific "small" questions, you are asking a question on a different level IMHO. Anyway, see last comment, I don't see any need for a cache to accelerate authentication at all. Session storage, maybe, authentication, no way. But even so you have to implememt a fallback should the data not be in the memcache, or make VERY sure there will always be enough RAM.

Comment: Last, why do you think about caching at this point? Sounds like you're still developing. From what little info there is I can't see that you really need to think about caching at this point.

Comment: @Mörre Of course I am still developing! It is for that I am thinking to a high-level system architecture! Quote (myself): What information do you need to know? Just say and I will provide those...

Comment: @Mörre I updated some information, if you are interested.

Comment: Why do you want to send authentication info between the sites, can't they just get the session data from the (same) database?
To give architecture advice one would have to see the WHOLE picture, what your task is from the customers point of view, and know their intentions and constraints. As it is you have to do this on your own, on the Internet you can then come for specific questions. Here you could only get the illusion of an answer, because in the end what does anyone here giving advice really know about the project?

Comment: @Mörre I updated question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you've explained so far, my answer would be no, I would not recommend this. Use a before_filter to authenticate, store the auth in the session.

Now if you had asked if you can use memcached as a session store, I'd say that it is possible. But the overly-complex message-passing scenario you've described would not be helped by using memcached.

Comment: said: "Use a before_filter to authenticate, store the auth in the session": In order to retrieve the 'user_id' for authentication purposes, the 'before_filter' should involve an HTTP(S) request to the 'users.pjtname.com' application? Then, I have to store that 'user_id' in the 'pjtname.com' session? - @Mark Thomas said: "But the overly-complex message-passing scenario you've described would not be helped by using memcached.": What do you mean with "would not be helped by using memcached"?

Comment: Yes, basically my proposal is to use standard Rails authentication conventions. If your auth routine in a before_filter needs to check with another server, so be it. But it only has to do that once per session, so caching is not a solution for that particular activity. The session itself *can* be stored in memcached, but the need for that vs. another session store (e.g. cookies) is not evident in your question.